# Can I apply for a France visa while I'm visiting in the UK

Tags: visas

I'm from south Africa and leaving the 5th of December 2016 for the UK. Don't have enough time to do my visa for France. Can I do it in the UK

Comment: To give a useful answer we will need to know your nationality and whether you are in the UK short term or longer, best with the kind of visa (if you have one) or what alternative.

Comment: Hi I'm a south African don't have enough time to do my France visa can i do it UK with my 2 months stay

Comment: It looks like a two month stay in the UK, as a tourist, is not enough reason to be allowed to apply for a Schengen visa from France, see the answer. (It would be nice if you click on the tick next to the answer to accept it.)

Comment: Hi- I used live in SA. Sorry, you need to sort out all Visa's at home! (unless you have an EU passport then you can just travel within Shengen) GOing out of UK is easy, getting back in... not so easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [French Government visa FAQ](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/faq-visas):

> **I usually live in Mali but am in Togo at present. Can I apply for a visa in Lomé? Can I send my visa application by mail to Bamako?**
>
> No. You must submit your visa application in person to the French consular office in your usual country of residence; you cannot apply by post.

You can apply for a French visa in your country of residence only.

Comment: While your source omits them, there are exceptions to this rule.

Comment: @phoog The exceptions listed in the Schengen Visa Code and elaborated in the associated handbook are often (if not mostly) ignored by the consulates.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Do you have a source to support that?  I certainly don't know of any evidence either way.

Comment: @phoog For example the French Goverment visa FAQ, which is quoted from here. Following the regulations (which are very vague and unprecise) or at least the examples in the handbook, there are several situations, in which a resident of Mali should be allowed to apply for a visa at a consulate in Togo. Instead, the question is simply answered with a 'no' from the French authorities.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I was hoping rather for cases in which people actually applied under circumstances clearly resembling the examples in the handbook and the consulate declined to consider the application.  The example in this question doesn't have any of the factors that the handbook suggests should justify an exception.

Comment: @phoog No, sorry, but TLScontact, the private company handling French visa applications in the UK, will e.g. not even let you book an appointment if you are a foreigner and do not have a UK residence permit. So in this case, the consulate will not even deciline to consider the application, but they bar you from the only possibility you have to even lodge an application.